# How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag

Tags: php, mysql, html

I created a MySQL database with a table using phpmyadmin.  I created this table with a BLOB column to hold a jpeg file.

I have issues with regards to the php variable `$result` here.

My code so far: (catalog.php):

```
<body>
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("dvddb");
  $sql = "SELECT dvdimage FROM dvd WHERE id=1";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  mysql_close($link);

?>
<img src="" width="175" height="200" />
</body>
```

How can I get the variable $result from PHP into the HTML so I can display it in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: _Whaaaat_ issues? You need to say what your code is doing wrong at the moment.

Comment: You can start by fetching those results

Comment: i am not clear of the syntax involved to display the BLOB image

Comment: @DamienPirsy How can i fetch these results?

Comment: Just my 2 cents and not related to your question, but I think you'd be better off storing the images on your file system and just referencing the path in your database.  You'll get better performance, and more flexibility as to where you store your images.

Comment: @john thanks! however is there tutorials on that? i actually have a folder in my localhost that contains all my images. how can i reference these paths in my database?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't.  You need to create another php script to return the image data, e.g. getImage.php.  Change catalog.php to:

```
<body>
<img src="getImage.php?id=1" width="175" height="200" />
</body>
```

Then getImage.php is

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dvddb");
$sql = "SELECT dvdimage FROM dvd WHERE id=?";
$result = mysqli_execute_query($link, $sql, [$_GET['id']]);
$image = mysqli_fetch_column($result);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Comment: but the thing is,I have nearly 50 images in my db.You have written for getting only one image.How can i display whole images in the page

Comment: To get a different image from the DB you simply change the `id` get parameter: `<img src="getImage.php?id=1" width="175" height="200" /> <img src="getImage.php?id=2" width="175" height="200" /> ...`

Comment: This answer is incorrect in that it IS possible, view Ilmari's answer.

Comment: Can you share the entire script. Would be very helpful

Comment: @DheerajMPai That *is* the entire script.  Although these days you'd use MySQLi instead of the mysql_* functions (this answer is 7 years old).

Comment: It may be 7 year old but still helpful for beginners. Anyway I shifted for python. So no issues anymore!@megaflop

Comment: when image is not display on img source then how can we identify path.

Answer (score 33):

Technically, you *can* too put image data in an img tag, using [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

```php
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $image_data ); ?>" />
```

There are some special circumstances where this could even be useful, although in most cases you're better off serving the image through a separate script [like daiscog suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/retrieving-images-from-database-and-display-under-html-tag/7793098#7793098).

Comment: I was wondering whether someone would suggest a data URI.  Not very efficient, IMO (no browser/proxy caching), but certainly worthy of a note.

Answer (score 4):

In case you store only the filename, while the image itself is stored in a file

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo 'img src="',htmlspecialchars($row['filename']),'" width="175" height="200" />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using PDO

#### Query

```php
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM products");
$products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

#### View

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
            <tr>
                ...
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars($product['product_name']); ?></td>
                <td>
                    <img 
                        src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($product['image']); ?>" 
                        width="100" 
                        height="100"
                    >
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

add `$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);` after your mysql_query();

your html `<img src="<?php echo $row->dvdimage; ?>" width="175" height="200" />`

Comment: You can't put raw image data inside an img src. OP clearly states the database stores the image data, not a path to the image file.