# php mysql image not display properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-upload, blob

I have following code for get image from my database table field.

```
public function getStudentses() {
    $students_data = array();       

    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "students 
        WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");   

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {             
        $students_data[$result['students_id']] = array(
            'students_id'        => $result['students_id'],
            'firstname'          => $result['firstname'],
            'filename'           => $result['filename'],
            'image'              => $result['image'],
        );
    }       
    return $students_data;
}
```

This is my HTML code for display image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" />
```

but when I render my page the image is not display properly its like some symbols like

```
s4�.���N����萗�p�A@4pbr��]�����F�G�>�v��W
```

Why its like this? How can I fix my error?

Comment: You may need to increase the mine head of the appropriate information

Comment: Are you storing the raw binary of the image?

Comment: yaa, i am using blob function

Comment: When you post code online, please make sure it is formatted nicely. I've formatted your code, please accept my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern browsers have this support for using raw image data as source.

You can try to use something like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" />
```

You should encode the image using [base64](http://php.net/base64_encode) and then output something like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($result['image']); ?>" />
```

I have use `image/png` for example. If your image is something else, you should use corresponding encType.

Just make sure to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://php.net/base64_encode).

Comment: Shouldn't `$result['image']` be html-escaped?

Comment: This is the best and the easiest solution I've found ever. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely need to change the header to an image

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: I suppose it's worth mentioning that in this case the output should also NOT contain any HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Most common practice for this (what I've seen) is to build html:

```
<img src="image.png.php?student_id=<?php echo $result['students_id']; ?>" />
```

And then `image.png.php`:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "students "
            "WHERE students_id = '" .(int)$request->getRequestParam('sudent_id') . "'"); 

// And now display raw content as image
$student = reset( $query->rows);
if( !$student){
   header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
   die( 'Blah blah... Blah blah blah');
}

header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $student['image'];
```

This way you'll be able to create links to images usable from whatever place you'll want (without any database access required on remote site).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are storing the raw binary of the image, you can do this:

```
'image'              => base64_encode($result['image']),
```

Then in the html:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" />
```

This assumes the image is a png.  If not, change the mime type accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is stored by this code

```
  s4�.���N����萗�p�A@4pbr��]�����F�G�>�v��W
```

its because you are just copying and pasting this code from database.
be sure where it stored the the name/id of the image and the path of the image and get the image by its path and id/name or  follow what Prasanth said to you.
this my help you 
[How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/retrieving-images-from-database-and-display-under-html-tag)