# Letting people upload an image to a post

Tags: php

I got a forum which you can post a title and description to it. So I got this database at the moment:

[image]

Now I want to be able to add an image to my post. I got a file upload page which I got from: 
http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php
Which I could use. But it wont make me see the image. Just the information of the image and the option to download it. It looks like this:
[image]

After I post my post, I want to be able to just see the image when I look at my post. I think there must be a different way to do this, right?

**EDIT:**
My post php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "accounts");
$mysqli2 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "forum");
$alles_goed=false;


if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$usernamecheck = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from account_information where username ='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'");

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $alles_goed=true;
    $description=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $title=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $usernameinsert=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

    if($usernamecheck->num_rows==0){
        $alles_goed=false;
    }   
    if($alles_goed==true){
        echo'<a href="questionprogramming.php">Back to programming</a>';
        $a=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $resultaat = $mysqli2->query("INSERT INTO questions (title, description, username, date_made) VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "', '".$usernameinsert."','".$a."')");

        }

}
if($alles_goed==false){
echo'<table>';
echo
<<<EOT
  <form action="newquestion.php" method="post">
  <tr><th><td><input type="text" size="108%" name="title"></td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td> <textarea name="description"  rows="20" cols="80" ></textarea></td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr></th>
  </form>

EOT;
echo'</table>';
}
}
?>
```

I know about the sql injection...

Comment: Can you show us your code. html / php etc. Also.. is that comic sans ms :P

Comment: Your awnser is probally overhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: @1ntello Honestly I dont know what I should put as code to even provide some extra information about the matter. I just dont know how to do what I am asking. And yes it is.

Comment: @1ntello The link I provided in my question shows the code I am mainly using.

Comment: @Alex Kind of but I still dont get that answer

Comment: It uploads the image to your server right, so you can just show it in a html `img` tag

Comment: @1ntello Nope cause if the img isn't in my directory it wont show the img. So when people upload the img, other people cant see the images.

Comment: So how do you ( want to ) render the image on the screen?

Comment: @1ntello No idea. It should be possible since on stackoverflow there is a possibility to add images to the post.

Comment: Yes, but on stackoverflow the image gets uploaded to imgur, and then it is rendered in the post by using an `img` tag. (according to chrome dev tools)

Comment: @1ntello is that a better way?

Comment: I actually don't know, but it is a way :p

Comment: Oh i was really confused by your question because i had no idea what you wanted, but i kinda do now :p

Comment: @1ntello It's still there.

Comment: Yeah i can't undo it once it's locked :)

Comment: @1ntello Well that sucks :S

Answer (score 0):

Loko you shouldn't put images in your database because of performance.
You store the path to the image in your database.

take a look at this for uploading your images.

http://www.phphulp.nl/php/script/php-algemeen/image-upload-script/1484/imageuploadscript/1086/

Good Luck.