# Load images stored in mysql to mysql stored html

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

So I'm making a website in PHP, and I've got the idea, that I would like to store both the HTML content of the pages and the content images in MYSQL. But as I was thinking about the implementation, I could not figure out a way to load the images to the HTML that I receive from the database.
(The process would be: page request->retrieve HTML from db->retrieve the images in html from db and insert them)

I haven't find any solution by googling yet, so I'm wondering if there is a routine solution for this problem? Any ideas are welcomed!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link will help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: just to be clear: you don't store HTML in your **data**base, you store DATA in **data**base. Unless you are a crawling engine of course and HTML is your data

Comment: It's true... storying HTML in the database is often a mistake. It makes redesigning and sharing data very hard. I don't see the point in storing images in the database either.

Comment: I'm only storing the pages content html in the database (aka html formatted text with images). The image part is only for experimentation.