# How to load image from the database in html?

Tags: php, mysql, html

This is my code.

```
<img src="getimage.php?id=1" alt="Delicious World" />
```

This is getimage.php

```
<?php

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("db_cupcake");
  $sql = "SELECT image FROM item WHERE id=$id";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);

  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['0'];
?>
```

I have directly stored the image in the database. I want to load those images in the webpage. Help me out.

Comment: Should be `mysql_query($sql);`.

Comment: use `base64_decode`....

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: Please use mysqli/PDO instead of mysql. mysql has option for vulnerabilities.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: this is also very unsafe and vulnerable to SQL Injection...

Comment: @Snickbrack I already wrote comment regarding unsafe friend.

Comment: @D4V1D its still not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first . If you are passing variables in the mysql query , then use quotations .Only then mysql will execute the query .
your query :- $sql = "SELECT image FROM item WHERE id=$id";
Instead use this query :- $sql = "SELECT image FROM item WHERE id='$id'";
And to display the image you can use

```
echo $row['image'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo $row[image];` not `echo $row[0];`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

// do some validation here to ensure id is safe

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_cupcake");  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM item WHERE id=$id");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  

header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 

echo $row['image'];

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Hi, 0 is not string. Please remove single quotes from 0. echo $row[0] is right or $row['image']