# How to take an image that's been uploaded to a database and display it on the browser in a table with text in the other rows and columns

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli

I have been searching before asking a question to solve my problem. But couldn't quite find anything that solves my problem. What I'm trying to do is upload pictures and some text to a database. The uploading works and the image gets stored as its binary data in a blob variable. The problem is that I want to display the text and images in a table as part of a dynamic html page.

I get all of the text to load to the page correctly, but the images only show up as blank squares (for lack of a better description). If you have any ideas, I'm all for it. Here is the code for everything.

```
<form action="http://notactualsite/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0">
<tr>
  <td>Select image to upload: </td>
<td><input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Where is this place?: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="destination" id="destination"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Why this place?: </td>
<td><input type="textbox" name="reason" id="reason"></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"></td>        
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now for the uploading php script/program

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$port = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database, $port);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];

if($image_size == true)
{


  $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO place2go VALUES ('$image_name','$image','$destination','$reason')";
  $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlStr);


}
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Location: http://www.is1500finproj-000564723.squarespace.com/place-to-go/');
exit();
?>
```

now the problem code

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$port = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database, $port);

if ($conn) {

//echo "<h1>TESTING</h1>";

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM place2go";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // create table structure
 // output data of each row: a single player with picture and name
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<h3>";
echo $row["placeName"]. "</h3>";
 echo "<table border=0>";
  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><img src='" . $image . " ' width='50%' /></td>";
   echo "<td valign=top style='font-size:10pt'>";
   echo $row["placeWhy"]. "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";    
}  
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: one of the reasons why you DON'T store the image in the db, sore the path in the db, and the file on the (hint in the name) file system

Comment: Or if you have to store the image in the db, (though you shouldn't) call a PHP script that gets the image content from the db and use the header function to change the content type to that of an image

Comment: Rather than saving the image to DB, move it somewhere and save a reference to that image. Add a timestamp and a random string or something to its name to make the name unique, move it somewhere and save the ref.

Comment: See this answer for the specifics of Kaleb Klein's answer.

[Change the retrieved image header.][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7793098/3585500

Comment: The website that I am using is weebly and as far as I can tell the website doesn't support storing information. If it does then I can change it to just upload it there instead. **I'll try everyone's suggestions later today and will let you know how it works**

Answer (score -1):

I will advice you to use a filesystem and also check the file to see that it really is a image file, but if you really want to save the image as binary use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

```
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Comment: no. don't use mysqli_real_escape_string on a blob, its not a string

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string is binary-safe - the documentation states: If binary data is to be inserted, this function must be used. ALL strings, whether user-supplied or not, need to be 
escaped if you don't use bound values. But that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: ah ok, never knew (never stored binary data in a db)