# I can not display BLOB image in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have some troubles displaying my blob image ,Here is the code I am using :

```
if ($pass==$dbpass&&$id== $dbid) {
$queryimage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id' "))[0];

header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
echo $queryimage;

@$_SESSION['id']=$id;
}
```

Comment: so what are "some troubles "?

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: You really shouldn't use `@` to suppress errors. Validate variables and log errors instead. Otherwise you will have a real pain debugging your code.