# Get the absolute url for BLOB image

Tags: php, blob, facebook-opengraph

I'm working with BLOB image in PHP. My images has no absulut url ( like this : www.example.com/my_image) . I need it because i'm woking with facebook open graph image sharing. How can i fix that?

Comment: How do you show your image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag)

Comment: i'm showing my image like this <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['image']); ?>" />

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work. Write a separate PHP program (call it maybe "loadimagefromdb.php") that emits the decoded image (based on an ID given in the query string, perhaps, which this program searches the db for) with a header of `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. Then in your `<img>` tag in the other file, you put that URL, e.g. `<img src="/loadimagefromdb.php?id=123">`.