# Trying to retrieve image from database using phpadmin

Tags: php

This is my php file.

```
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("food",$con);

         $SQL = "SELECT image FROM info WHERE Type='Fruit Pizza' ";
         $RESULT = mysql_query("$SQL");


        $ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($RESULT);

          header("Content-type: image/png");
          echo $ROW['image'];

    ?>
```

This is how i add the image into database.

```
 $data = addslashes(file_get_contents('dinner2.png'));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO info(image, Name, Price, type) VALUES('$data','Fruit Pizza','8', 'png')");
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?? The problem is everytime i try to retrieve the image it show a small grey box instead of the picture.Anyone can help??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: The `mysql_*` api is deprecated.

Comment: What does `$ROW['image']` actually output? My guess is that if it returning anything useful is that the path isn't correct.

Comment: And you're adding text `$data`, change `'$data'` to `"$data"` or just $data, without apostrophes

Comment: @Goover i cant add into database if without apostrophes

Comment: @j08691 ['image'] is column in my table

Comment: @ron oh yes, I'm sorry I've misread the line, didn't saw opening `"`