# Echoing image from MySQL Database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, echo

I have been trying to echo images from my database using PHP. I have tried various solutions on the forum with no success. I am just getting a blank image as an output.

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
    $id=$rows['id'];
    $LastName=$rows['LastName'];
    $FirstName=$rows['FirstName'];
    $Year=$rows['Year'];
    $Press=$rows['Press'];
    $Description=$rows['Description'];
    $Title=$rows['Title'];
    $image=$rows['image'];


    echo '<div class = "paragraph">' . $LastName . '<br/>'. $FirstName . '<br/>' . $Year . '<br/>' .  $Press . '<br/>' . $Title . '<br/>'. $Description . "<img src='image/".$row['image']."' />" . '</div>' ;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: try preceding the `image/".$row['image']` with a slash ~ ie `/image/".$row['image']` etc

Answer (score 2):

You're echoing the image as `$row['image']`, but the only prior references to the image are `$rows['image']` (note the s) and `$image`. Update the echo statement to use either of these and not `$row['image']`.

Edit: This will not fully fix your issue. As noted in a comment to your question, you will need to do some finagling to actually display the image as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getquery)){
    $id=$rows['id'];

    /*
       assuming the `image` directory is relative to the root
       and not the directory from which the script runs then
       a leading slash might be the issue.
    */
    echo "
    <div id='{$id}' class='paragraph'>
        {$rows['LastName']}<br/>
        {$rows['FirstName']}<br/>
        {$rows['Year']}<br/>
        {$rows['Press']}<br/>
        {$rows['Title']}<br/>
        {$rows['Description']}
        <!--<img src='/image/{$row['image']}' />-->
        <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, {$rows['image']}' alt='' title='' />
    </div>";
}
```

If you store the mimetype of the image when you save it to the db then you would substitute the proper mime/content type in above ~ ie: `image/png`, `image/gif` etc so that might then become something like:

```
<img src='data:{$rows['mimetype']};base64, {$rows['image']}' alt='' title='' />
```

Comment: the images aren't even in a directory, they are in a database. i need them to echo from the DB.

Comment: so you have stored the base64 encoded image content and need to output that? generally the format would be something like `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, /<BASE64_STRING>" />`

Comment: yeah, that's essentially what i need. I'm checking around now for a way to accomplish this.