# Can Some one correct this where i am wrong?

Tags: php, joomla

Description --> I just want to fetch image in my web page from data base i had given BLOB type to database where i am storing image , how do i fetch that image , in this code i am getting small icon of image with corrupted format .

```
<?php

 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "****",  "******","****");
 $find_data =mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM ashish " );
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_data)){

 $current=$row['weblink'];$asdf=$row['webrate'];$imag =$row['weblogo'];

 $ima =$row['weblogo'];

 }

 ?>
 <form action="ashishdb" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div><p>WebSite Link :<input type="text" name="weblink">    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     Websites Rating : <input type="text" name="webrate">   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Website Logo : <input type="file"   name="weblogo"></p>

  <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn_file"></p>

  </div>
   <table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
   <th>A</th>
   <th>A</th>
   <th>A</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $current ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $asdf  ?></td>

     <td><img src=<?php echo $ima ?> ></td> 


        </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
     </body></html>
```

Comment: You need to pass image folder path..

Comment: where do i ahve to pass that ?

Comment: this will `<?php echo $ima ?>` give u only last image from while, secondly u are missing the quotes, this `<img src=<?php echo $ima ?> >` should be `<img src="<?php echo $ima ?>" >` if `$ima` contains full image path

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Comment: it is showing small icon of like some corrupted image

Comment: img src takes a URL, not raw image data (except under certain cases, but dumping the raw binary output of a table blob isn't one of them)

Comment: it is on joomla , dont know the exact path of folder , but i can store image in its media folder ? how to retrieve it from there , can any one help ?

Comment: what is the path of folder? add it before `$img`,  if `$img` only contains the image name

Comment: Do you mean BLOB? If so, are you storing the raw image data in your database? Something like this will work for you `<img  src="data:image/png;base64,<?=$ima?>" />`

Comment: @Steve - BLOB is binary, not a base64 string.

Comment: How to know path in joomla media ?

Comment: @AshishTripathi: for u https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Joomla!_templates

Comment: Thanks for the link , but i havn't found any image  path related things

Answer (score -2):

if your "ashish" table "weblogo" column contains the image's path or url, you can try :

```
<img src="<?php echo $ima; ?>" >
```

or

```
<img src="<?=$ima?>" >
```

Comment: That's just markup fix, not an answer to his real question. You can't show blob data like that.

Comment: maybe he stored the image's url in his database. Isn't it?

Comment: His first sentence in the question says: _"from data base i had given BLOG type to database where i am storing image..."_. I would rather think that "BLOG" is a typo for BLOB and not URL.

Comment: He tagget joomla Sir Magnus Eriksson. In Joomla, I would rather know images don't stored as BLOB, the stored thing is image url.

Comment: @YavuzYILDIZ: u r right, but still it will only display the last record not all

Comment: BLOB is only a type for a colum where i am  storing the name of image ,