# How to display an image from a mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the structure of my mysql table crij_personne :

- id
- photo longblob
- image_name varchar(64)

My html code is the following:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" />
```

The code for uploading the image to my database:

```
$imagetmp=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['photo'] ['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['photo']['image_name']);
$imagetmp= base64_encode($imagetmp);
$sql = "INSERT INTO crij_personne (description, photo, image_name) VALUES ('".$_POST['description']."','$imagetmp',' $image_name');"; 
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
```

The code for displaying the image on a web page is:

```
echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64, '.$row['photo'].'">';
```

But nothing is happening... I'm doing something wrong, obviously.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: why you are using base64_encode ?

Comment: Take at look at this documentation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

**For insertion values into the database.**

```
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['photo']['image_name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO crij_personne (description, photo, image_name) VALUES ('".$_POST['description']."','$imagetmp',' $image_name');";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) echo "New record created successfully";
else echo "Error: " .  mysqli_error($conn);
```

**For retrieval of image from Database**

```
$connectDb = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","DatabaesName"); //You need to replace with your own credentials 
$query= "SELECT * FROM crij_personne WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $connectDb ->query($query);
$mysqli_fetch_array=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $mysqli_fetch_array['image_name'] ).'"/>';
```

And then retrieve, I hope you will get the correct output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But what is "$db"?

Comment: @nad now black background is appearing due to the header funcation. 
Now, when you will echo right database field, then for sure you image will be on screen.