# Symfony display blob value

Tags: mysql, image, symfony, blob

I have a project to Symfony 3. With MySQL I have a blob field for a profile user image (in bin extension).

[image]

This one is saved from my entity user with the preUpload. (I had set the path new file for test only)

[image]

But I can't read the file. How can I do this?

The dump of the entity:
[image]

Comment: You should add *how* you're trying to use the image blob to the question. Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag might be useful.

Comment: i would to read the file in html src !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display blobs as images with the following HTML5 tag.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<base64 code here>" />
```

If you're using this in a Symfony controller it would look like:

```
/// ... controller code

$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User:class)->find($id);
$img = $user->getImg();

// ... more controller code

return $this->render('AppBundle:yourpage.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'img' => base64_encode($img),
]);
```

And in twig, you'd display the base64 data in an image tag like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img }}" />
```