# how do I display an image saved in the db as a longblob?

Tags: html, mysql

I've stored a blob image in the database but I can't see it. I wrote this code

```
$queryi = "SELECT Foto  FROM bhk   WHERE Cod_Bhk = '".$Codice."' INTO DUMPFILE 'immagine.jpg'";

$resulti = mysqli_query($connessione_al_server,$queryi);
```

html code:

```html
<img id="imgcaricata" class="mySlides" src="immagine.jpg" style="height:600px; width:auto;max-width:500px;">
```

Comment: What does that code do? What is not working yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid if your blob has the mime type jpeg

```
echo '<img id="imgcaricata" class="mySlides"  
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $resulti["Foto"] ).'" 
style="height:600px; width:auto;max-width:500px;" />';
```

Or try it with a separate php script like https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793098/5193536

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(  $resulti["Foto"] ); ?>" id="imgcaricata" class="mySlides" style="height:600px; width:auto;max-width:500px;"/>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it