# Escape a string full of " and ' in PHP

Tags: php, binary, escaping

I need to escape a string that has a lot of " and '. The string is a binary from a database. I have this:

```
$String64 = '<a data-String64="'.$binary64.'">Link</a>';
```

So the `$binary64` has some text like `target:"29", width=100'height=200...`

So my problem is that the `"'` are closing the `data-String64` before it can output the entire variable. I have tried addslashs(), but nothing good.

How can I escape this?

This is what I have tried:

```
$String64 = "<a data-string64='${binary64}'><b><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></b></a>";
$String64 = "<a data-string64='{$binary64}'><b><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></b></a>";
$String64 = "<a data-string64=\'${binary64}\'><b><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></b></a>";
$String64 = "<a data-string64=\'$binary64\'><b><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></b></a>";
$String64 = "<a data-string64=\"$binary64\"><b><i class=\"fa fa-eye\"></i></b></a>";
```

Comment: Do you really need those `'` and `"`s any problem if you remove them ?

Comment: like i said, it is a binary from my DB. So i need it because the binary is a PDF file that ill render in an iframe.

Comment: Heh, blob file works in other way.

Comment: lol i cant var_dump all of it, its a binary of 40kb. i can post some part      v   $  �  �      &����  v   $          ��������cO��� ��W��@N����#Iq�Ie�_��c�Ժ��B|Γ����f��ƐF�/9��y�Ҙ���z�)�L�Tk��%�T��0SJ��#���N��0rl���N�L�%�Ƿc�.��y�=�^n����0�����Ù Mp�{o�;���_�wf.�%^�x���dK\�*N��d�I�Tm)B�MM:[oa,C�6aFVrY��O�&�%@DL>6�Q����u��j*����Ot��B�T�<l3�����r8�ҍV��C&sl�|�ȣ�*y#�ތ}ː��OR+�H���tԒL,zwr��1�zގ����D�u� �&�0x����̵��}�K��[�,F�����-B !N�ܦ?��朳#�ۃ�N �al�I�Xآ9��Q���ɾW:R,�P�J�%Y�I�u��ЗZ��ؽx\{�z�s@ BjŹ��Ko;�ޕ���R��(y�!�5qR!4м�V�Ɗ����@bU�t�F�

Comment: I see , as long as you use it like binary it should be fine (like write to a pdf file) why you want to display it as text?

Comment: i needed that in a data- to get it by JS, but i guess ill do it by ajax and forget this method

Comment: Yes I've done that in ajax just make the request as binary and browser will treat it as such. Things is HTML is supposed to be a TEXT-only document therefore can't handle the binary content that's the reason we use EXTERNAL Font files to render custom fonts/emojis

Answer (score 0):

You need to make next:

```
$String64 = '<a data-String64="'.base64_encode( $binary64 ).'">Link</a>';
```

or

```
$String64 = '<a data-String64="'. base64_encode($binary64->load()) .'">Link</a>';
```

Documentation of [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

For your tag try:

```
echo '<embed 
      style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;" 
      type="application/pdf" 
      src="data:application/pdf;base64,' . base64_encode($binary64->load()) . '"></embed>';
```

Comment: lol thats not it. you did a simple variable ````$var = ''TTTT;```` the problem is that i have multiple " and ' inside my var

Comment: still not my case. Like i said, i have multiple " and ' at same time. Try to make your var like this: ````var = 'TT "TT'T '; you will see what is my problem

Comment: tried both, wont work. First still doenst escape and second gives an php error. What you are doing there i did that in my javascript.
````var htmlText = '<embed style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;"'
                            + ' type="application/pdf"'
                            + ' src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
                            + escape(string64)
                            + '"></embed>';
````

Comment: mysql i guess ill do this in another way. ill get it by ajax directly in my JS and forget this data-. Guess it will be better for performance and everything.

Comment: @AlexisGarcia, as you wish, also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag)